# NodeJS/Http: long delay after socket timeout; save to leave socket open?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, http

Consider this simple server. It simply returns the content of the request as text:

```js
import {createServer} from 'http'

const server = createServer((req, res) => {
  let data = ''
  req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk
  })

  req.on('end', () => {
    res.end(data)
  })
})

server.listen(56690, 'localhost', () => {
  global.console.log('server started')
})
```

When I post to this server, the first request, takes ~505 ms. Subsequent requests take only a couple of milliseconds, as long as I don't run into the keepAliveTimeout, which as of Node V8 is 5+ seconds. That is, if I wait for 5 seconds after a post, the next request again takes >500 ms:

- initial post: response time 505ms
- immediate post: response time 5ms
- immediate post: response time 5ms
- immediate post: response time 5ms
- (wait for 6 seconds)
- post: response time 505ms

I understand that the node server destroys the connection socket after `server.keepAliveTimeout` (or `server.timeout`). Also, I know that I can change the timeouts by tweaking those settings, e.g. `server.keepAliveTimeout = 30000` to increase the keep alive timeout to 30 seconds.

I can also completely deactivate the timeouts by either

- setting `server.keepAliveTimeout = 0` ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_keepalivetimeout)) and `server.timeout = 0` ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout)) or
- subscribing to the `timeout` event without closing the provided socket there, ie. `server.on('timeout', (socket)=>{})` or `server.onTimeout(0, ()=>{})`. In this case, the sockets aren't destroyed automatically on timeout (see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback): "However, if a callback is assigned to the Server's 'timeout' event, timeouts must be handled explicitly.")

My questions:

- Why does it take so long (500ms!) for Node to reestablish the socket after a timeout?
- Is there any way to reduce this cost except not closing the socket?
- Is it even correct to not close the socket on timeout or to set an infinite timeout? Am I leaking resources?

Environment:

- Node: v8.9.4 and v9.5.0
- OS: Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 R2
- CPU: Mobile Core i7 4x2.9 GHz and Xeon 4x2.4 GHz

Comment: I just ran a few tests and this indeed happens. I had never experienced this behaviour before because I never use a stock Node server. With Express, this restart time doesn't happen. I always get 7-8ms response time, even in `NODE_ENV=development` (which is supposed to be slower than `production`)

Comment: @JeremyThille Maybe Express disables the timeouts. Might be worth investigating.